MDM iOS Pre-defined Login App Config.xml?
I’m looking for someone to help me find a solution for my MDM users. There has to be a clearer resource to this so maybe I’m not searching in the right place.
My current scenario: iPads enrolled in MDM (ManagedEngine) with Apps managed from Apple Business Manager installed onto the devices.
What is the best way to simplify logging into apps without typing the username and password for each app on each device? For example if I have Netflix app with Name@gmail.com/Pass123 and this is what would be used for all my users. I’d like for them to just open apps and I’ve already predefined the login details.
I know there is an APP Config.xml setting per app. Would this be the place to define login for the app? OR can I integrate an SSO solution that links their Apple ID to my other accounts?
Any input would be helpful. Thank you.
--
Tried searching for information on setting this up and I don't see anything related to user login/pass for App.Config.xml profiles. Maybe I'm not thinking about it the right way.
I just setup an SSO solution with Auth0 to see if this would work but I've still trying to set it up.
If someone has done this or similar that can point me to a good resouce guide I'd appreciate it.

Any solution would need to be built in to the app. There is no generic solution. If you are talking about an app you have built then you can do it however you like. If you are talking about apps from the App Store (like Netflix as an example) then there is no solution unless Netflix have added such a function.
